# Right justification of numbering in ListOfFigures in tufte-book

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, tufte-book

I realize this should be an easy fix, but I cannot solve this on my own and cannot find quite the right solution on StackExchange.

I'm using tufte-book style and would like the numbering for the ListOfFigures to be right justified (without filling dots), rather than the default, shown here:

[image: List of figures]

I realize there are a number of macros that can be included that will achieve this but every one I've tried alters the layout in unacceptable ways.

There must be a simple option within standard tufte-book for ensuring right-justified page numbering.

Any hints?

---

@Simon Dispa's solution, below, indeed ensures the numbers are right justified.  Alas, I guess I didn't realize that right justification would lead to such a ragged (and ugly) typesetting, where the captions extend beyond the page numbers, as shown here:

[image: Simon Dispa's solution]

I suppose what is also needed is to narrow the text area (just for ListOfFigures) so that the page numbers are cleanly right justified without any short figure captions extending to their right.

Is that an easy fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

Also added a patch to increase the width of figure numbers from 2em to 3em. (when double digit chapter numbers are reached)

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

%***************************************  added
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter   
\patchcmd{\@tufte@lof@line}{0em plus 1fil}{-4em plus 1fil}{}{} % move page numbers to the right
\patchcmd{\@tufte@lof@line}{\qquad}{\hfill}{}{} % make page number right justified  
\patchcmd{\@tufte@lof@line}{2.0em}{3.0em}{}{} % more width to the figure number
\makeatother        
%***************************************

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents    
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\setcounter{chapter}{10}
\chapter{Eleven}    
\setcounter{figure}{19}

\begin{figure}
\caption{XX}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\setcounter{page}{562}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a  posteriori.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your code indeed works (+1), but as you can see in my updated post, now some of the (short) figure captions in the list extend to the right of the page numbers, leaving a rather ugly and poorly legible layout.  I confess it was my naivety that led me to think that just right justification of the page numbers would suffice when in fact I think the text columns need also to be narrowed.  Any quick fix for that?  (Of course, I want this *only* on the ListOfFigures pages... not anywhere else in the book!

Comment: @David G. Stork You are using an earlier code between updates. See the last update and the figure with long captions.

Comment: Simon Dispa:  *Perfect*!  Thanks so very much.  (accept)